What does 方 + だけマシ mean?

……お前は、どうせあたしがどこにいたところで探しに来るんだろ!


えぇ……まあ


それならさっさと見つかってやった方が言いがかりつけられないだけマシだと思って同じ場所にいてやってるんだ

The convo is a back and fort. I don't quite understand the last part
I understand "思って同じ場所にいてやってるんだ" "I thought and so I waited at the same place" what could 方が言いがかりつけられない here mean?
"Not being accused of being found earlier/easier?"

The basic structure is さっさと見つかってやった方がマシ and 言いがかりつけられないだけ modifies マシ.

It's not "accused of being found" but "accused of trying to escaping from you".
If she had moved from that place, the other person would have spent time trying to find her and would have accused her. If she stays there, at least she doesn't have to worry about being blamed for that.

それならさっさと見つかってやった方が言いがかりつけられないだけマシだと思って同じ場所にいてやってるんだ
So I thought it's better to let you find me right away so that you can't make a false accusation (that I tried to escape from you). That's why I'm staying in the same place.


だけ used here is だけに right?
